# How to access Rails / Paperclip S3 assets in show view, aws-sdk 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

Using the new AWS Ruby SDK (aws-sdk 2.2.18) and Paperclip, I have managed to upload an audio file to S3.

The tutorials and documentation I have found all refer to the 1.x version of aws-sdk, eg: [Heroku tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3)

This is my code so far:

model

```
has_attached_file :audio 
validates_attachment_content_type :audio, :content_type => [ 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/x-mpeg', 'audio/mp3', 'audio/x-mp3', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/x-mpeg3', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/x-mpg', 'audio/x-mpegaudio' ]
```

edit form (simple_form)

```
<%= f.input :audio, as: :file %>
```

controller

```
def update
  if @sentence.update(sentence_params)
    s3_bucket = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket(Rails.application.secrets.aws_s3_bucket)
    s3_filename = get_s3_filename(@sentence)
    s3_obj = s3_bucket.object(s3_filename)
    s3_obj.put(body: sentence_params[:audio])
    redirect_to @sentence, notice: 'Sentence was successfully updated.'
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

The problem I am having is when I try to access the link in the show view to play the audio, it doesn't point back to S3.

show view

```
 <%= link_to @sentence.audio.url %>
```

renders

```
 /system/sentences/audios/000/408/166/original/sample_audio.mp3?1456335849
```

How can I access the asset in S3, and specifically play the audio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the s3_credentials option in your has_attached_file line.

```
  has_attached_file :download,
                :storage => :s3,
                :s3_credentials => Proc.new{|a| a.instance.s3_credentials }
```

There is some more information available in the [Paperclip docs.](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3)

Once you properly set up the s3 connection, you won't need any of the code you have in your update method.

Calling

```
<%= link_to @sentence.audio.url %>
```

will automatically return the correct URL pointing to the file stored in the S3 bucket.

Hope that helps!